# laravel insert rows into a mysql table causes duplicate rows to be inserted

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to insert one row into my mysql table from my web app which I set up using the Laravel Homestead environment. Here is the function in a controller I created.

```
public function insertToTable2Attempt2()
{
 DB:: table("rookies3") -> insertGetId (
 array("name" => "Emma", "calls" => 80)
 );
 }
```

Here is the code in the routes.php file.

```
Route::get("insert2", ["as" => "insert2",
"uses" => "tableController@insertToTable2Attempt2"]);
```

The idea is that when a user navigates to the right weblink one row will be added to my table in mysql. However, multiple rows, all identical, are being added instead of just one. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So whenever a user go to the link `example.com/insert2` the data `["name"=> "Emma", "Calls"=> 80]`  will be added to your table `rookies3`. Right?

Comment: Yea thats the idea. Right now multiple rows are added and I want to add just one

Comment: Truncate your table `rookies3` and try to hit the url only once. I don't see any problem in your code. But if you hit your url multiple times, multiple entries will be added.

Comment: Yea I have tried that. I am definitely hitting the url only once but the row is being added twice in the mysql table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So when I type in example.com/insert2 the function gets run even if I don't press enter and the web browser doesn't load the link. Then when I press enter and the web browser loads the link the function gets called again. Since each time the function gets called a new row is added to my mysql table, I was getting multiple rows added.